# Prove that the limit of ${ \frac{(-1)^n}{n}}= 0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification

Prove that the limit of $s_n = {\large \frac{(-1)^n}{n}}= 0$ .

This is what I have so far, based on a walk-through of a similar question in my textbook, but I don't really understand what I'm doing.

There exists a number $N$ such that $n\gt N$ implies:

$$\left|\dfrac{(-1)^n}{n} - 0\right|\lt \epsilon \Rightarrow\left|\dfrac{(-1)^n}{n}\right|< \epsilon \Rightarrow \frac{1}{n} < \epsilon \Rightarrow \frac{1}{\epsilon} < n$$

Now, let $\epsilon > 0$, $N= \frac{1}{\epsilon}$.

Then $n > N$ implies $n > \frac{1}{\epsilon}$ which implies $\epsilon > \frac{1}{n}$.

If $n > N$, then $\left|\dfrac{(-1)^n}{n}-0\right| < \epsilon$.

Therefore the limit of $s_n = 0$.

Comment: But when you say 1/n < E there I must say that -1/n < E too. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: This is because we are taking $|(-1)^n|$ and this is equal to 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am assuming that you're referring to a limit as $n \to \infty$, but this needs to be specified. You should separate what seems to be scratchwork (there exists a number $N$ such that ...) from your formal proof. It's correct, however, up to typos. It can be written more cleanly as:

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given, and set $N = \frac{1}{\epsilon}$. Then if $n \ge N$, we have $\frac{1}{n} < \frac{1}{N} = \epsilon$, giving

$$\left|\frac{(-1)^n}{n} - 0\right| = \frac{1}{n} < \epsilon$$

as desired.